# CSS Table Layout Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the code below, specifically the line "table.ScanData, th, td" that is setting the borders for all the other tables on my page but NOT ScanData.

```
table.ScanData
{
 margin-left:5px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
table.ScanData, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table.ScanData td
{
    padding:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
table.ScanData th, table.ScanData td
```

instead of

```
table.ScanData, th, td
```

Comment: That stops it affecting the other tables but ScanData doesn't have an internal border.

Comment: can you show a piece of html-code where ScanData table is used?

Comment: Oops, that prompted me to look at my html, I'd been playing before hand and left a bit of inline code that was over-riding your code. Working now thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:
`.ScanData table, th, td ....`

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MbdMW/

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
table.ScanData th, table.ScanData td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```